# How can I write HTML anchor tags in a .CSV file?

Tags: magento, csv, export-to-csv

I have searched and was unable to find any information about a solution to my problem.

I have a large database of 1000+ products formatted for upload to Magento e-commerce software.

The descriptions are written in HTML which works fine except for the anchor tag.

When I use a double quote it is replaced by the ǎ character. When I save the file as a .csv from any spreadsheet program the links look like:

```
< a href=ǎhttp://link.comǎ> Some Link < /a>
```

I read that I need to use a double quote to escape and use a single quote in a CSV file i.e. the anchor tags I have written now look like:

```
< a href=""http://link.com""> Some Link < /a>
```

Didn't work.

In total I have tried:

- using different spreadsheet software including iWork Numbers, Microsoft Excel, OpenOffice Calc and Google Docs
- formatting all cells in a new spreadsheet as plaintext, importing individual descriptions
- trying to escape the quote by using double quotes (not sure if I actually need it to be a triple quote because I'm trying to escape just the quotation mark?)

I'm fairly certain this is a problem with the way .CSV files handle quotation marks, but I'm unsure how to write a quotation mark in a spreadsheet so it will be correctly rendered by .CSV as a single quote instead of a special character.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

To store this line in a CSV file:

```
Somelink,<a href="http://link.com">Some Link</a>
```

you need to write it like this:

```
Some Link,"<a href=""http://link.com"">Some Link</a>"
```

If you're going to escape double quotes `"`, wrap the whole cell/value with double quotes `"`

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Ruel. I have a new, albeit easier problem to solve. I replaced all double quotes with a star (" replaced with *), because I am not using a star anywhere else in the data. I am using Google Refine to clean up my data, but I need a command to replace the stars with double quotes -- refine uses quotes to demark the string. I tried to use a find & replace with Vim (which uses / to demark the replacement string), but it splits up the CSV formatting. Opening in Excel or Numbers allows me to find and replace -- but replacing the * with a " leads to ǎ on export!

Comment: In other words: I now understand I need to wrap the contents of the 'description' column in double quotes, but I am still having trouble with getting those quotes to format properly after being exported to a .csv from a spreadsheet program. I may need to run a Perl command from the terminal, but I'm not that good with Perl.